# Accordion menu wondering

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, accordion

I was wondering. I have this simple accordion menu:

THe problem is, I want to, when I have one opened menu, when I click on another one, to close the previous one automatically. In other words, only one should be opened at a time...

What do you think, what would be the best solution to this?
No jQuery, I want vanilla JS :)

```js
var accordions = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
    
    for (var i = 0; i < accordions.length; i++) {
      accordions[i].onclick = function() {
        this.classList.toggle('is-open');
    
        var content = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (content.style.maxHeight) {
          // accordion is currently open, so close it
          content.style.maxHeight = null;
        } else {
          // accordion is currently closed, so open it
          content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
        }
      }
    }
```

```html
<button class="accordion">Accordian #1</button>
        <div class="accordion-content open">
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas deleniti molestias necessitatibus quaerat quos incidunt! Quas officiis repellat dolore omnis nihil quo, ratione cupiditate! Sed, deleniti, recusandae! Animi, sapiente, nostrum?
          </p>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas deleniti molestias necessitatibus quaerat quos incidunt! Quas officiis repellat dolore omnis nihil quo, ratione cupiditate! Sed, deleniti, recusandae! Animi, sapiente, nostrum?
          </p>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas deleniti molestias necessitatibus quaerat quos incidunt! Quas officiis repellat dolore omnis nihil quo, ratione cupiditate! Sed, deleniti, recusandae! Animi, sapiente, nostrum?
          </p>
        </div>
    
    
        <button class="accordion">Accordian #2</button>
        <div class="accordion-content">
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas deleniti molestias necessitatibus quaerat quos incidunt! Quas officiis repellat dolore omnis nihil quo, ratione cupiditate! Sed, deleniti, recusandae! Animi, sapiente, nostrum?
          </p>
        </div>
    
    
        <button class="accordion">Accordian #3</button>
        <div class="accordion-content">
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas deleniti molestias necessitatibus quaerat quos incidunt! Quas officiis repellat dolore omnis nihil quo, ratione cupiditate! Sed, deleniti, recusandae! Animi, sapiente, nostrum?
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to iterate through all accordions since you can save the last opened one. See my solution below.

```js
var accordions = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var openAccordion = null;

for (var i = 0; i < accordions.length; i++) {
  accordions[i].onclick = function() {
    if (openAccordion != null && openAccordion != this) {
      openAccordion.classList.toggle('is-open');
      var content = openAccordion.nextElementSibling;
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    }
    
    this.classList.toggle('is-open');

    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight) {
      // accordion is currently open, so close it
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      // accordion is currently closed, so open it
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
    
    openAccordion = this;
  };
}
```

```css
.accordion-content {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<button class="accordion">Accordion #1</button>
<div class="accordion-content open">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas deleniti molestias necessitatibus quaerat quos incidunt! Quas officiis repellat dolore omnis nihil quo, ratione cupiditate! Sed, deleniti, recusandae! Animi, sapiente, nostrum?
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas deleniti molestias necessitatibus quaerat quos incidunt! Quas officiis repellat dolore omnis nihil quo, ratione cupiditate! Sed, deleniti, recusandae! Animi, sapiente, nostrum?
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas deleniti molestias necessitatibus quaerat quos incidunt! Quas officiis repellat dolore omnis nihil quo, ratione cupiditate! Sed, deleniti, recusandae! Animi, sapiente, nostrum?
  </p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Accordion #2</button>
<div class="accordion-content">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas deleniti molestias necessitatibus quaerat quos incidunt! Quas officiis repellat dolore omnis nihil quo, ratione cupiditate! Sed, deleniti, recusandae! Animi, sapiente, nostrum?
  </p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Accordion #3</button>
<div class="accordion-content">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas deleniti molestias necessitatibus quaerat quos incidunt! Quas officiis repellat dolore omnis nihil quo, ratione cupiditate! Sed, deleniti, recusandae! Animi, sapiente, nostrum?
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over all the accordions and remove the `is-open` class when any accordion is clicked:

```
var accordions = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");

for (var i = 0; i < accordions.length; i++) {
  accordions[i].onclick = function() {

    for (var j = 0; j < accordions.length; j++) {
      accordions[j].classList.remove('is-open');
    }
    accordions[i].classList.toggle('is-open');
  }
}
```

Then hide the accordions using CSS:

```
.accordion:not(.is-open) {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your feed back :) 
Good idea!